# Change customWorkspace based on branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins pipeline and I am getting the following error when running a function to get CustomWorkspace: `No such DSL method '$' found among steps`.

```
def getLabel() {
    // Which server to run this on.
    return "php7a"
}
// Choose the site name based on git name and if it is a Pull Request or branch.
def getSitename() {
  if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'updates') {
    SITENAME = "reo"
    if (env.CHANGE_BRANCH && !env.CHANGE_FORK){
      return "${SITENAME}-${env.CHANGE_BRANCH.toLowerCase()}"
    }
    else {
      return "${SITENAME}-${env.BRANCH_NAME.toLowerCase()}"
    }
  }
  else {
    // Set the project name, most likely the git repo name.
    if (env.CHANGE_BRANCH && !env.CHANGE_FORK){
      return "${env.CHANGE_BRANCH.toLowerCase()}"
    }
    else {
      return "${env.BRANCH_NAME.toLowerCase()}"
    }
  }
}

def projectName() {
    return "myproject"
}


/**
 * Get custom workspace path.
 *
 * @param string projectName
 *   Project name.
 * @param string siteName
 *   Site name.
 */
def getCustomworkspace(String projectName,
                       String siteName) {
  if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'updates') {
    return "/var/www/${siteName}"
  }
  else {
    return "/var/build/${projectName}-${siteName}"
  }
}

...
...

  agent {
    node {
      label "${getLabel()}"
      customWorkspace "${getCustomworkspace(${projectName()}, ${getSitename()})}"
    }
  }
...
...
```

Comment: I don't see any functions or definitions for getLabel or getSitename functions, though they are being referred in customWorkspace

Comment: @SushantSonker Just added them.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the customWorkspace line as below

```
customWorkspace "${getCustomworkspace('${projectName()}', '${getSitename()}')}"
```

Comment: This did not work. It actually sent those values as the string `${projectName()}` instead of the values returned from the functions.  I ended up just finding a workaround by not passing any parameter but instead calling the functions inside my function.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to call the function with parameters but I was able to call the functions inside my function so I just did this:

```
/**
 * Get custom workspace path.
 */
def getCustomworkspace() {
  if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'xupdates') {
    return "/var/www/${getSitename()}"
  }
  else {
    return "/var/build/${projectName()}-${getSitename()}"
  }
}
```

```
customWorkspace "${getCustomworkspace()}"
```